# Xamarin XAML Previewer Design Data Bindings

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to set up a Design Time Data binding in a Xamarin XAML page so I can utilise the previewer to design my page more quickly. I have set up a static class which contains my data, but when I preview it does not show me the bound data.

How do I get the binding to work? I am trying it with the `Test` property

**XAML**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TechsportiseApp.Data;assembly=DesignTimeData"
    BindingContext="{x:Static local:DesignTimeData.ViewModel}"
    x:Class="TechsportiseApp.Views.Timer" x:Name="ParentView" Title="Timer">
    <Entry Margin = "3"  Text="{Binding Test}" />
</ContentPage>
```

**DesignTimeData.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;
using TechsportiseApp.Models;

namespace TechsportiseApp.Data
{
    public class DesignTimeData
    {
        public static class ViewModelLocator
        {
            private static TimerViewModel timerVM;
            public static TimerViewModel ViewModel => timerVM ?? (timerVM = new TimerViewModel());

            public class TimerViewModel
            {
                public ObservableCollection<Timing> Timings { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Timing>
                {
                    new Timing { Position = 1, BatchCode = "A", Elapsed = "01:02:03.001", EndTime = DateTime.Now, StartTime = DateTime.Now, Id = 1, RaceId = 111 }
                };
                public List<RaceOption> RaceOptions { get; set; } = new List<RaceOption>
                {
                    new RaceOption { Id = 1, RaceId = 2, Colour= "Red", OptionName="5k" },
                    new RaceOption { Id = 3, RaceId = 4, Colour= "Blue", OptionName="10k" },
                    new RaceOption { Id = 5, RaceId = 6, Colour= "Green", OptionName="15k" },
                    new RaceOption { Id = 5, RaceId = 8, Colour= "Yello", OptionName="20k" },
                };

                public string Test = "Bind Test";

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/design-time-data.

Comment: I already looked there, I followed the guide linked below and also looked at Montemagno’s blog. Best I can tell this is right but i am obviously wrong otherwise I would t have posted https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-previewer/

Comment: Test should be a public property on your View Model/Binding Context that implements INotifyOnPropertyChanged.

Comment: If you just kept it simple, [it would work](https://imgur.com/UJMkgyQ)...:O)

Comment: Interesting @jsanalytics, but how can I keep it simple to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TimerViewModel
        {
        private string _test = "Bind Test";

            public string Test
            {
                get
                {
                    return _test;
                }
                set
                {
                    value = _test;
                    //implement your INotifyOnPropertyChangedHere...
                }
            }

            /// the rest of your view model code


        }
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't work. I'm not looking to change the property - its meant to be a general fixed data set to be used at Design Time so essentially I can display the dat from this binding. I am using this as a test so I can utilise it for an ItemSource (Which I would otherwise pull from a web API)so the standard view model implemented will take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not properly defined your class. Change the below structure

From

```
namespace TechsportiseApp.Data
{
    public class DesignTimeData
    {
        public static class ViewModelLocator
        {
private static TimerViewModel timerVM;
            public static TimerViewModel ViewModel => timerVM ?? (timerVM = new TimerViewModel());

            public class TimerViewModel
            {
                public ObservableCollection<Timing> Timings { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Timing>
                {
                    new Timing { Position = 1, BatchCode = "A", Elapsed = "01:02:03.001", EndTime = DateTime.Now, StartTime = DateTime.Now, Id = 1, RaceId = 111 }
                };
                public List<RaceOption> RaceOptions { get; set; } = new List<RaceOption>
                {
                    new RaceOption { Id = 1, RaceId = 2, Colour= "Red", OptionName="5k" },
                    new RaceOption { Id = 3, RaceId = 4, Colour= "Blue", OptionName="10k" },
                    new RaceOption { Id = 5, RaceId = 6, Colour= "Green", OptionName="15k" },
                    new RaceOption { Id = 5, RaceId = 8, Colour= "Yello", OptionName="20k" },
                };

                public string Test = "Bind Test";

            }
        }
    }
}
```

To

```
namespace TechsportiseApp.Data
{
    public class DesignTimeData
    {
private static TimerViewModel timerVM;
            public static TimerViewModel ViewModel => timerVM ?? (timerVM = new TimerViewModel());

            public class TimerViewModel
            {
                public ObservableCollection<Timing> Timings { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Timing>
                {
                    new Timing { Position = 1, BatchCode = "A", Elapsed = "01:02:03.001", EndTime = DateTime.Now, StartTime = DateTime.Now, Id = 1, RaceId = 111 }
                };
                public List<RaceOption> RaceOptions { get; set; } = new List<RaceOption>
                {
                    new RaceOption { Id = 1, RaceId = 2, Colour= "Red", OptionName="5k" },
                    new RaceOption { Id = 3, RaceId = 4, Colour= "Blue", OptionName="10k" },
                    new RaceOption { Id = 5, RaceId = 6, Colour= "Green", OptionName="15k" },
                    new RaceOption { Id = 5, RaceId = 8, Colour= "Yello", OptionName="20k" },
                };

                public string Test = "Bind Test";

            }
        }
}
```

This should resolve your issue

Comment: No that hasn't worked - still not showing the bound data.

Comment: Does your TimerViewModel has Constructor with parameter ? What happens when you run your application, do you see value/result bound to the control?